# Scapy - OSError: [Errno 90] Message too long

Tags: python, scapy

The error message "OSError: [Errno 90] Message too long" appears each time I use scapy to send a packet that is longer than 1514 bytes.

Is it possible to send a packet that is bigger than this size without having to break it up into smaller pieces?

```
import os
load = os.urandom(1481)
pkt = Ether()/IP(dst="192.168.10.104")/load
print("len=",len(pkt))
sendp(pkt)
```

```
len= 1515

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_83506/53727884.py in <module>
      3 pkt = Ether()/IP(dst="192.168.10.104")/load
      4 print("len=",len(pkt))
----> 5 sendp(pkt)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py in sendp(x, inter, loop, iface, iface_hint, count, verbose, realtime, return_packets, socket, *args, **kargs)
    334     need_closing = socket is None
    335     socket = socket or conf.L2socket(iface=iface, *args, **kargs)
--> 336     results = __gen_send(socket, x, inter=inter, loop=loop,
    337                          count=count, verbose=verbose,
    338                          realtime=realtime, return_packets=return_packets)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py in __gen_send(s, x, inter, loop, count, verbose, realtime, return_packets, *args, **kargs)
    289                     else:
    290                         dt0 = ct - p.time
--> 291                 s.send(p)
    292                 if return_packets:
    293                     sent_packets.append(p)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py in send(self, x)
    557     def send(self, x):
    558         try:
--> 559             return SuperSocket.send(self, x)
    560         except socket.error as msg:
    561             if msg.errno == 22 and len(x) < conf.min_pkt_size:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/supersocket.py in send(self, x)
     47     def send(self, x):
     48         sx = raw(x)
---> 49         sent = self.outs.send(sx)
     50         try:
     51             x.sent_time = time.time()

OSError: [Errno 90] Message too long
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by changing the MTU (Maximum Transfer Unit) of your interface.  This is the maximal number of bytes a frame can contain.

On linux:

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 2000 up
```

where `eth0` is the name of my ethernet interface and `2000` is the new MTU (it is 1500 by default on an ethernet nic).  Then your script works fine.

It seems also feasible on windows (not tested):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-change-mtu-settings-in-windows-10/5c36c250-a0e8-47ee-b01c-de22139dc297

Note however, that there is good chance that the packet will be ignored by the receiving interface because it is too large.